# C# se congelo y no acepta nuevos cambios

Tags: c#

Mi problema es que quiero agregar nuevos cambios a mis formularios, pero cada vez que agrego nuevos metodos o acciones estos no se visualizan en la aplicacion.

Actualmente le quite un boton al formulario y ejecute ese mismo formulario pero me aparecio el boton que habia eliminado.

Formulario en el editor de visual studio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Formulario al momento de correrlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solucion a este problema es la posible cache que se acumulo durante todo el proceso de desarrollo y lo solucione volviendo a generar el proyecto en Visual studio.

1. Primero ve al recuadro de Explorador de Soluciones
2. despues de ahi ponte sobre la solucion de C#
3. luego da clic izquierdo te aparecera un nuevo menu
4. dentro de ese menu dale clic en volver a gener.

Answer (score 1):

No encuentro relacion alguna en el error al abrir tu nuevo formulario, parece que tu segundo formulario contiene un error no manejado y el primer formulario es el que obtiene la excepcion, comenta el codigo:

```
this.Close();
```

y encapsula el resto en un bloque:

```
private void btnCompra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    try 
    {
        this.Hide();
        Modal_compra compras = new Modal_compra();
        compras.ShowDialog();
        //this.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Oye creo que es un error de C# o visual studio, es que intento ponerle simples mensajes a los metodos en todos los botones pero me siguen haciendo la instruccion anterior, es como si no respondieran o se hubieran quedado congelados y quisiera saber si hay forma de borrar como el historial o algo que lo este bloqueando.

Comment: Necesitaria ver mas del codigo o la clase completa para poder entender si no es una excepcion no controlada en alguna parte u otro tipo de error

Comment: Rodriguez ya eh actualizado la publicacion, por si gustas observarla

Comment: Puede que tengas un error en el archivo de diseño, despliega en la flecha de la izquierda en el explorador de soluciones tu formulario y busca el archivo [NombreDeTuFormulaio].Designer.cs codigo erroneo